# In Editor Template, Kendo Combobox DataSource does not hit the Controller method to populate the combobox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datasource, partial-views, mvc-editor-templates, kendo-combobox

`Editor Template` has a `Kendo.ComboBox()` with the `DataSource` reading from a `Controller`:

```
  .DataSource(source =>
  {
    source.Read(read =>
    {
      read.Action("TheController", "TheMethod").Data("getReportId()");

    });
 })
```

The Editor Template is defined for the Grid's column in a `Partial View` page:

```
co.Bound(c => c.Name).Title("Name").EditorTemplateName("_TheEditor");
```

The Controller's method GetData, I think, should be called when Grid is populated:

```
public JsonResult GetData(int itemID)
{
    MyModel model = new MyModel();
    var dataList = model.GetData(itemID);
    ViewData["DataList"] = dataList;

    return Json(dataList.ToList() , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

What's wrong with my logic?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [editor template demo](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-custom), also refer to the demo for [cascading combo boxes](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/combobox/cascadingcombobox) to see how data is passed to combo box datasource read. 
I feel the error in your code is in the editor template .Data("getReportId()")
remove the brackets.

```
.DataSource(source =>
  {
    source.Read(read =>
    {
      read.Action("TheController", "TheMethod").Data("getReportId");

    });
 })
```